# Как в javascript подключить файл php с параметром?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть часть кода

```
cols.push($("<td>")
    .attr('class', 'namecell')
    .append($("<span>")
            .attr('class', 'accountname')
            .data('id', accounts[index].index)
            .text(accounts[index].accountName)
    )
    .append($('<a>')
            .attr('title', "Edit")
            .attr('class', 'cellOptionButton')
            .on('click', {
                    "index": accounts[index].index
            }, function(event) {
                    edit(event.data.index);
            })
            .append($('<span></span>')
                    .attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-wrench')))
    .append($('<a>')
            .attr('title', 'Details')
            .attr('class', 'cellOptionButton')
            .on('click', {
                    "index": accounts[index]["index"]
            }, function(event) {
                    showdetail(event.data.index);
            })
            .append($('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>')))
);
```

Как вместо кода `.text(accounts[index].accountName)` (Шестая строка в коде)

подключить php файл с параметром?

`.text(/mod.php?param=accounts[index].accountName)` (Эту строку не знаю как сделать.)

А в этом файле будет `file_get_contents` и тд.
Можно конечно и не подключать файл, там код не большой, а прямо в JS прописать как-то немного php.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вам необходимо использовать метод `load`. Пример использования: `$("#id").load("test.php");`

Comment: Как код поставить в `.text()` чтобы файл вывелся именно в `.text(файл)`?

Comment: @steep `load` рабоатет как вывод содержимого файла или как результат его выполнения. Поэтому после него уже будет текст. В теории можно запихнуть результат `load` в переменную и эту переменную уже поместить в `text`

Comment: А на практике можно как?

Comment: @steep ну в вашем случае можно так попробовать: `.append($("<span>")
            .attr('class', 'accountname')
            .data('id', accounts[index].index)
            .load('file.php')
    )`. Не знаю, на сколько важно `accounts[index].accountName`. Если надо совместить эти записи, то делать надо немного иначе

Comment: @steep кстати можно попробовать сделать так: `let php FileResult; $.get('file.php', function(data){
    phpFileResult = data;
});.text(accounts[index].accountName + phpFileResult)`. Но я не очень уверен, что вам это подойдет.

Comment: Ниче что `$.get(` выполняется __асинхронно__?

Comment: @u_mulder ничего, если код поместить внутри него далее. Либо использовать систему `promise`

Comment: Не грузится файл ни как.

Comment: Попробуйте просто сделать на пустой странице код: `$('span').load('phpFile.php');`. Если он отработает, то вы делаете что-то не так. И, возможно, вам php файл ничего не выводит, вот и нет результата.